# If link exist on the page, add class on click, javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

At first, I check if button with class prices__link exist on the page, and then I need to open modal block on click.
For one button it works, but not for second one.
Could you please help what is missing?

HTML:

```
<a class="prices__link" href="">Show more</a>
<br>
<a class="prices__link" href="">Button 2</a>
<div class="popup-business popup-business--hide">Modal</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var popupPrices = document.querySelector('.popup-business');
var buttonPopupPricesOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.prices__link');
var buttonPopupPricesItem = document.querySelector('.prices__link');

if (buttonPopupPricesOpen.length !== 1) {

  buttonPopupPricesItem.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    popupPrices.classList.toggle('popup-business--hide');
  });

  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking for with javascript is something like:

```js
const popupPrices = document.querySelector('.popup-business');
const buttonPopupPricesOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.prices__link');

// for each element with the class found, add an event
buttonPopupPricesOpen.forEach((buttonElem) => {
  buttonElem.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    popupPrices.classList.toggle('popup-business--hide');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's what I was looking for.